# beamer inserts line break at strange place

Tags: beamer, itemize

The following code inserts line break only after two words, that is, after "Some text". If you remove the `quote` environment in the example, that doesn't happen. It's as if latex couldn't break lines within `\emph{. . .}`.

Does somebody know what's causing this? The problem happens both with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`. I use the latest mactex (texlive 2023) and update the installation using `tlmgr` quite often.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1609]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide title}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  Some text
  \emph{if abcdefghijklm is large and fast enough}
  than on classical composers.
  \begin{quote} hello \end{quote} % <- comment out
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add an empty line before the `quote` environment. If the quote environment starts in a new paragraph, it is easier for latex to find a good place for a line break in the previous paragraph.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Thanks! That works, but you sound as if this is a common and known problem. Why haven't I seen it for 30 years using LaTeX? I've never developed a habit of inserting a blank line before display environments.  Is it a recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the `quote` within the same paragraph as the item body, it will have both the indent from the itemize list and from the list used internally in `quote`. As a result, the (in your example invisible) colourbox around the `quote` is too wide to fit in the reminder of the page.

To avoid this problem, leave an empty line before the `quote` to make sure it starts in a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1609]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide title}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  Some text
  \emph{if abcdefghijklm is large and fast enough}
  than on classical composers.
  
  \begin{quote} hello \end{quote} % <- comment out
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]